# Scaling/Zooming a SpriteBatch

Tags: libgdx, spritebatch

I am working on my first game with LibGDX and coming from ActionScript3 I am used with the possibility of scaling things more or less the way I want. I know it works different in LibGDX, but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to achieve what I am trying to do.

I have a camera set up (OrthographicCamera), a SpriteBatch where I render different items(textures) and what I want is to be able to scale and move a group of items, while the rest remain intact. I know that I can zoom the camera itself, but this applies to all the elements int he SpriteBatch.

If you worked with ActionScript before, imagine you have the stage (this is my SpriteBatch) where I render different DisplayObject. Some DisplayObjects have other DisplayObjects inside. I calculate these offsets (item.x is parent.x + offsetInParent). Now what I want is to be able to scale one such DisplayObject with ease.

Thanks.